# Returning while-loop values as multiple rows in SQL Server instead of multiple result sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following T-SQL, used to generate some random values:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < 100
BEGIN

select
    Random_String =
    substring(x,(abs(checksum(newid()))%36)+1,1)+       
    substring(x,(abs(checksum(newid()))%36)+1,1)+
    substring(x,(abs(checksum(newid()))%36)+1,1)

from
          (select x='0123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUWXYZ%#-=+') a

          SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```

This works well enough, except every string is returned as, what looks like, an independent result set.

Is there a way to refactor that query to return every value as one row in the same result set?

Environment is MS SQL Server 2008.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a temporary table of one column and insert each row in. Then use one select statement at the end, that way you have one result set of 100 rows. If you want one row, then do the same thing, but with a temp table of 100 columns and use update instead of insert. But the second case sounds like an ugly idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to do this kind of thing is to forget about looping in t-sql. Using a numbers or tally table is a much better way to go about this.

```
WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a cross join E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E2
    )

select
    Random_String =
    substring(x,(abs(checksum(newid()))%36)+1,1)+       
    substring(x,(abs(checksum(newid()))%36)+1,1)+
    substring(x,(abs(checksum(newid()))%36)+1,1)

from
(select x='0123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUWXYZ%#-=+') a
cross join cteTally t
where t.N < = 100
```

Comment: Blast, beaten by a minute!  But I do like your use of `VALUES` more than the `UNION ALL` method.  It looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it using a tally table:

```
;With Tally (N) As
(
    Select  0   Union All
    Select  1   Union All
    Select  2   Union All
    Select  3   Union All
    Select  4   Union All
    Select  5   Union All
    Select  6   Union All
    Select  7   Union All
    Select  8   Union All
    Select  9
), Numbers (N) As
(
    Select      Row_Number() Over (Order By A.N) Num
    From        Tally   A   --  10
    Cross Join  Tally   B   --  100
    Cross Join  Tally   C   --  1000
    Cross Join  Tally   D   --  10000
    Cross Join  Tally   E   --  100000
), LookupString (X) As
(
    Select  '0123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUWXYZ%#-=+'
)
Select      Random_String = substring(x,(abs(checksum(newid()))%36)+1,1)+       
                            substring(x,(abs(checksum(newid()))%36)+1,1)+
                            substring(x,(abs(checksum(newid()))%36)+1,1)
From        LookupString  
Cross Join  Numbers
Where       N <= 100
```